# Zend Framework - Pass variable from one controller to another on redirect

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a small form in Zend Framework, and when it's sent and valid, I want to pass the $id to another controller where I will display some information about that id in another view.

The form and validation is done, but I just can't seem to figure out how to pass the $id to another controller.

I have the following code:

```
if ($this->_request->isPost()) 
    {       
        $formData = $this->_request->getPost(); 
        if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
            die($id);
        } else {
            $form->populate($formData);
        }
    }
```

And now it shows the id when valid, but I want to redirect it to lets say formAction, with the $id variable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only 1 variable you can simply send it as a GET request. so

```
$this->_redirect('/controller/action/varname/varvalue')
```

would work. And in the controller, you can retrieve it by using

```
$myvar = $this->_getParam('varname', false);
```

You can do this with more than 1 variable, simply append name/value pairs to the URL.

On the other hand, if you have a lot of data, then you might need to either POST it using cURL or use Zend Session to store it in controller A and then retrieve in controller B

Comment: It's only 1 variable, so i'll try this out. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, I tried your code but i get nothing when echo'ing out.

Comment: Can you paste the URL your page redirects to here? For example, the url should look like this `http://mywebapp-dev.com/search/q/zend` . Here if you did `$this->_getParam('q', false)` you would get `zend`

Comment: /index/bon/64/ is the URL and when I echo $this->_getParam('bon', false); I get nothing...

Comment: if you're accessing your index method in indexController, then it has to be `/index/index/bon/64` unless you are using a custom route.

Comment: It redirects me to the homepage when adding another /index/. The action where my post validation is is called testAction, and and goes to bonAction.

Comment: You have to give the full controller/action path even if you're in the same controller. So it has to be `/controller/action/bon/64` Craft your URL like that and it will work

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do a `_forward` I would suggest you put the id in question in the session using `Zend_Session` or, depending on the internals of your application, in the registry using `Zend_Registry::set('variablename', $id);`

If you can live with a `_forward` instead you should be able to get the data from the request object in the other controller, just as you did in this one.

Update:

Forward, forwards your call to the specified controller and action. 
Forward to another controller/action.

Kinda works like `$this->_forward('nameOfAction', 'nameOfController', 'module', paramsArray)`. The action must be given, but all other params are optional. The `paramsArray` could be used to pass data if needed.

The following is fetched from the source documentation about `_forward`

```
/**
 * Forward to another controller/action.
 *
 * It is important to supply the unformatted names, i.e. "article"
 * rather than "ArticleController".  The dispatcher will do the
 * appropriate formatting when the request is received.
 *
 * If only an action name is provided, forwards to that action in this
 * controller.
 *
 * If an action and controller are specified, forwards to that action and
 * controller in this module.
 *
 * Specifying an action, controller, and module is the most specific way to
 * forward.
 *
 * A fourth argument, $params, will be used to set the request parameters.
 * If either the controller or module are unnecessary for forwarding,
 * simply pass null values for them before specifying the parameters.
 *
 * @param string $action
 * @param string $controller
 * @param string $module
 * @param array $params
 * @return void
 */
```

So if you would forward to an action `foo`in controller `bar` you could do

```
$this->_forward('foo', 'bar');
```

and in `BarController`

```
public function fooAction() {
  // Get the request and continue to work with it here
  $request = $this->_request();
  ...
}
```

Comment: _forward is internal - it doesn't fire new request. It tricks ZF into thinking the forwarded module/controller/action triplet is the original one ;)

Comment: Thanks, but how do i pass a variable in the paramsArray? Because now i have this: $this->_forward('bon', 'index', null, 'id => $id'); but that ofcourse doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

There are options how to do this (mainly using Zend_Session), but the need for this smells of bad design. What exactly are you trying to do using this?